# Heroku can't find this particular image path. Why?

Tags: node.js, image, heroku, deployment, path

I have deployed an app at heroku.

Everything works fine, locally. However, when deployed heroku can't find two img. **index.html** contains exactly this, at different places :

```
 FOUND     <img src="img/bamboo-black.png" height="27"> <div class="loaderWrap">
 NOT FOUND <img class="loader" src="img/ajax-loader-black.gif"></div> 
 NOT FOUND <img src="img/person-placeholder.jpg" class="mainPicture" width="150">
```

Why would it work locally and fail on heroku ? I don't understand.

Comment: Try putting a [leading slash](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/56840/what-is-the-purpose-of-leading-slash-in-html-urls) in the URLs `<img src="/img/ajax..."`

Comment: Actually at first, there were 2 leading salsh. I thought that was the problem, so I removed them. But it wasnt :/

Comment: Two leading slashes are a short form for "http://", entirely different from a single leading slash.

Comment: My bad, I mean I was using one leading slash per html attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Did you commit those two files to the repo?

Do a `git status` and see if they're in the 'new files' section.

If you've committed the files, then login to the Heroku dyno and verify they are there.

```
$ heroku run bash
```

You can also try a restart.

```
$ heroku restart
```

Comment: Yes I have. I've been deploying regularly for 3 weeks now

Comment: It didn't work. I think i'll try to move and grab them from a CDN or something

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.

For those who might encounter the same problem someday : i used a CDN (cloudinary)

I replaced :

```
<div class="loaderWrap"> <img class="loader" src="img/ajax-loader-black.gif"></div>
```

By this :

```
var $loader = $.cloudinary.image( LJ.cloudinary.loader_id, LJ.cloudinary.displayParamsLoader );
            $loader.appendTo( $('.loaderWrap') );
```

It works fine now.